# different binary when i encrypt and decrypt txt file using AES in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt txt file using AES in C.
but I got problem.
I watched binary of plain.txt and decrypted.txt. 
so There's not same binary.

I want to make same binary.
How to fix this problem ?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
void encrypt(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int fsize = ftell(ifp);
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int outLen1 = 0; int outLen2 = 0;

    unsigned char *indata = malloc(fsize);
    unsigned char *outdata;
    unsigned blocksize;

    unsigned char ckey[] = "thiskeyisverybadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";
    unsigned char ivec[] = "dontusethisinputaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";

    fread(indata, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, ifp);

    EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ckey, ivec);

    blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&ctx);
    outdata = malloc(fsize * 2 + blocksize + 15);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, outdata, &outLen1, indata, fsize);
    EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, outdata, &outLen2);
    fwrite(outdata, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, ofp);

    free(indata);
    free(outdata);
}

void decrypt(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int fsize = ftell(ifp);
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int outLen1 = 0; int outLen2 = 0;
    unsigned char *indata = malloc(fsize);
    unsigned char *outdata;
    unsigned blocksize;

    unsigned char ckey[] = "thiskeyisverybadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";
    unsigned char ivec[] = "dontusethisinputaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";

    fread(indata, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, ifp);

    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ckey, ivec);

    blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&ctx);
    outdata = malloc(fsize * 2 + blocksize + 15);

    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, outdata, &outLen1, indata, fsize);
    EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, outdata, &outLen2);
    fwrite(outdata, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, ofp);

    free(indata);
    free(outdata);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fIN;
    FILE *fOUT;
    errno_t error;
    char buf[255 + 1];

    if ((error =fopen_s(&fIN,"C://Projects/test_curl/Debug/plain.txt","rb"))!=0 {
        strerror_s(buf, 255, error);
        printf("fopen_s error : \n%s\n", buf);
        return 0;
    }
    if ((error = fopen_s(&fOUT, "C://Projects/test_curl/Debug/cyphertext.txt", "wb")) != 0) {
        strerror_s(buf, 255, error);
        printf("fopen_s error : \n%s\n", buf);
        return 0;

    }

    encrypt(fIN, fOUT);
    fclose(fIN);
    fclose(fOUT);

    if ((error = fopen_s(&fIN, "C://Projects/test_curl/Debug/cyphertext.txt", "rb")) != 0) {
        strerror_s(buf, 255, error);
        printf("fopen_s error : \n%s\n", buf);
        return 0;
    }
    if ((error = fopen_s(&fOUT, "C://Projects/test_curl/Debug/decrypted.txt", "wb")) != 0) {
        strerror_s(buf, 255, error);
        printf("fopen_s error : \n%s\n", buf);
        return 0;
    }

    decrypt(fIN, fOUT);
    fclose(fIN);
    fclose(fOUT);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically not following the letter of the instructions on how to invoke the API's you're calling. Among the things wrong:

- The `EVP_EncryptUpdate` function encrypts the given data, storing the size of the encryption output in its size out param, which you're basically ignoring. The same is true on the decryption side.
- You blast over the initial encrypted/decrypted data block with your invoke of `EVP_EncryptFinal` (and `EVP_DecryptFinal`), in contradiction to precisely what the libcrypto documentation specifically warns you NOT to do.
- Your output size in both functions is wrong. You're writing `fsize` bytes, which was the *input* size, not the output size. the latter is provided in the output-size params which you're ignoring (see the first item in this list).

The following functions do what you want. Compare them to what you had (wishful thinking on my part). I took the liberty of not using `encrypt` as the name, as that is a commonly provided DES function in unistd.h.

```
void encrypt_data(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(ifp);
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int outlen=0;
    unsigned char *indata = malloc(fsize);
    unsigned char *outdata;
    unsigned blocksize;

    unsigned char ckey[] = "thiskeyisverybadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";
    unsigned char ivec[] = "dontusethisinputaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";

    fread(indata, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, ifp);

    EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ckey, ivec);

    // round up to nearest block size, this will add a complete
    //  block of additional padding if the input size is perfectly
    //  a factor of the block size
    blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&ctx);
    outdata = malloc(((fsize + blocksize)/blocksize) * blocksize);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, outdata, &outlen, indata, (int)fsize);
    fwrite(outdata, 1, outlen,  ofp);
    EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, outdata, &outlen);
    fwrite(outdata, 1, outlen, ofp);

    free(indata);
    free(outdata);
}

void decrypt_data(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(ifp);
    fseek(ifp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int outlen = 0;
    unsigned char *indata = malloc(2 * fsize);
    unsigned char *outdata = indata + fsize;

    unsigned char ckey[] = "thiskeyisverybadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";
    unsigned char ivec[] = "dontusethisinputaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";

    fread(indata, 1, fsize, ifp);

    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ckey, ivec);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, outdata, &outlen, indata, (int)fsize);
    fwrite(outdata, 1, outlen, ofp);
    EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, outdata, &outlen);
    fwrite(outdata, 1, outlen, ofp);

    free(indata);
}
```

Those *will* work.

Best of luck.

Comment: It's works for me ! Thank you soooo much !